# How to Implement django - pre_save and post_save?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I have tried much to implement django's pre_save and post_save, but still I am unable to generate the signal.
What I have is:

```
Class Client(models.Model):
    .
    .
    . # some fields

Class ClientView(models.Model):
    .
    .
    . # some fields
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = u'clients_view'
        verbose_name = 'Client'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clients'

    def save(self):
        models.signals.pre_save.send(sender=obj, instance=self)
        obj = Client(**self.obj_to_dict())
        obj.save()
        models.signals.post_save.send(sender=obj, instance=self, created=True)

    def obj_to_dict(self):
        return {'pk': self.pk, 'name': self.name,
                'i_company': self.i_company, 'is_reseller': False}
```

Please Tell me where I am doing it wrong??

Comment: You're referencing an uninitialized variable `obj` in the first line of the `save` method (the variable is initialized in the second line)

Comment: You shouldn't be implementing any of that code. Both the sending of signals and the creation of the object are already done for you by the base model class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```
Class ClientView(models.Model):
#...your model definition...

def your_def(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            client_view = instance
            #.....

post_save.connect(your_def, sender=ClientView)
```